# Explicitly Linking to Classes in DLL's

Tags: c++, borland-c++

I have a class that is currently in a .lib file:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) ReportData {
public:
        list<FileData *> ReportFileData;
        list<SupressionData *> ReportSupressionData;

        static char *ClientName;
        static char *DataRecieved;

        std::string GenFileConfTemplate();

        ~ReportData()
        {
                ReportFileData.clear();
                ReportSupressionData.clear();
        }

};
```

I can add this lib file to my project and create instances of this class no problem.
My question is, how can i move this to a DLL and dynamically load it, and create instances of this class. What i'm wanting to do is move some common functionality into this dll and share it across multiple projects.

I want to be able to re-compile the dll if needed when changes are made and have the projects use the must recent version; as of now, using a lib, I have to recompile every project after I recompile the dll for the changes to take place, and because the way this system was originally designed, there are 100+ projects that will use this lib/dll and I don't want to recompile 100 different projects each time a change is made.

So, please give me your expert opinions on how i should go about doing this.

I'll be using the dll inside of my projects like so:

```
    ReportData *rd = new ReportData();

    ReportData::ClientName = "test";

    rd->ReportFileData.push_back(new  FileData("testing", 10, 1));
    rd->ReportFileData.push_back(new  FileData("testing 2", 20, 1));

    std::cout << rd->GenFileConfTemplate();

    delete rd;
```

I ended up with something like this:

```
typedef Foo* (__stdcall *CreateFunc)();

int main()
{
        HMODULE dll (LoadLibrary ("..\\LLFileConfirmDLL\\LLFileConfirmDLL.dll"));
        if (!dll) {
                cerr << "LoadLibrary: Failed!" << endl;
                std::cin.get();
                return 1;
        }

        CreateFunc create (reinterpret_cast<CreateFunc>(GetProcAddress (dll, "create")));
        if (!create) {
                cerr << "GetProcAddress: Failed!" << endl;
                std::cin.get();
                return 1;
        }

        Foo *f = create();
        cerr << f->Test();


        FreeLibrary (dll);

        std::cin.get();

        return 0;
}
```

---

```
struct FOOAPI Foo
{
        Foo();
        virtual ~Foo(); 
    virtual int Test();
};

Foo::Foo()
{
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
}

int Foo::Test()
{
        return 5;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Foo* __stdcall create()
{
        return new Foo;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this the way COM does it:

1. Export a CreateInstance() function.
2. Pass a void** and unique identifier to CreateInstance().
3. Your consuming DLL calls LoadLibrary() on the library DLL and calls CreateInstance().
4. CreateInstance() does the new ReportData and returns it in the void** out param.

Edit:

Something like:

```
extern "C"
BOOL CreateObject(REFCLSID rclsid, void** ppv) {
    BOOL success = false;
    *ppv = NULL;
    if (rclsid == CLSID_ReportData) {
        ReportData* report_data = new ReportData();
        if (report_data) {
            *ppv = report_data;
            success = true;
        }
    } else if (...) {
        ... other objects ...
    }
    return success;
}
```

Of course, now you have to worry about things like who will free the object, making sure the DLL doesn't get unloaded, etc.

See also [DllGetClassObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680760(VS.85).aspx), [DllCanUnloadNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690368(VS.85).aspx), etc.

Comment: could you provide a small sample?